# How to change maximum viewable tables from 250 to anything in PhpMyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to increase my list of tables to 5000 in phpmyadmin

The documentation says this:

```
 $cfg['MaxNavigationItems']
 Type:  integer
 Default value: 250
```

I have tried to set it in the back end to no avail under

```
settings>navigation panel>Maximum items in branch
```

How can I do this, I have tons of table on multi site that I often need to delete and don't want to have to keep clicking next and next after only 250 entries...

[image]

Comment: Set `$cfg['MaxTableList'] = 5000;` in `config.inc.php`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you to juergen d , for other beginners, add the code

```
 $cfg['MaxTableList'] = 5000;
```

to the file  **config.inc.php**, it's not in there to be changed, so can't find it , *it needs to be ADDED to the file.*

File is located at

```
C:\xampp\php
```

in my case.

PS. There is a box in Phpmyadmin to change the value, but it doesn't work, even after restart, not sure why, but the solutions above works.

Comment: Million dollar question - why do you even use that crappy software? There are so many better tools out there (SQLYog, MySQL Workbench), which don't require http server to run.

Comment: I don't know...I thought PhpMy Admin was the only choice, I use XAMPP, and all web hosting companies use PhpMyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Login to phpmyadmin

Go to setting

and Select Features

Select Database

change Maximum tables

[image]

Comment: Getting this error on Save:
Cannot save settings, submitted form contains errors!
Maximum tables
Value must be less than or equal to 250!